# How to vlookup another excel sheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub lookuphcpcs()

On Error GoTo errorbox:
Dim hcpcs_code As Long

Dim desc As Variant
hcpcs_code = ActiveCell.Value

If Len(hcpcs_code) > 0 Then
    desc = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Active_cell, 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\[Fruit Code.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$7, 2, False)
    MsgBox "Description for HCPCS Code " & hcpcs_code & " is """ & desc & """"

Else
    MsgBox "You did not enter any input!"    
End If

Exit Sub

errorbox:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "No Description found under HCPCS list!"
End If

End Sub
```

I am not able to put table array value under Vlookup in VBA to point to another excel sheet.

How do I do that?

Comment: Is the other workbook open?

Comment: Yes the other workbook is open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**, when working with `Vlookup` you need to handle errors, such as when `Vlookup` was unable to find a match, you can use `If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(....` to achieve this.

**Second**, in your case you don't need to use `On Error GoTo errorbox:`, just use the `Vlookup` error handling I wrote in the first point.

**Third**, you can use `If Trim(ActiveCell.Value2) <> "" Then` to verify there is a valid text or number inside `ActiveCell` rather than empty spaces.

**Fourth**, you should avoid using `ActiveCell`, and use fully qualified object instead.

**Last**, you want to make sure `"Fruit Code.xlsx"` workbook is open before using the `Vlookup`, as suggested by @Tim Williams in the comments above.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub lookuphcpcs()

Dim desc As Variant
Dim SourceWb As Workbook

' error trapping in case Fruit Code workbook is closed
On Error Resume Next
Set SourceWb = Workbooks("Fruit Code.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If SourceWb Is Nothing Then
    Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Fruit Code.xlsx") ' open workbook if it's closed
End If

If Trim(ActiveCell.Value2) <> "" Then ' make sure cell has a string other than space
    If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(ActiveCell.Value2, SourceWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B7"), 2, 0)) Then
        desc = Application.VLookup(ActiveCell.Value2, SourceWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B7"), 2, 0)
        MsgBox "Description for HCPCS Code " & ActiveCell.Value2 & " is """ & desc & """"
    Else
        MsgBox "No Description found under HCPCS list!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "You did not enter any input!"
End If

End Sub
```